# npm specifying path for prettier

Tags: node.js, npm, prettier

I am not able t get prettier working.

Here is the script I added in package.json

`"prettier:write": "prettier --write 'src/*.{ts}'"`

and when I run `npm run prettier:write`, it says

`No files matching the pattern were found: "src/*.{ts}".`

Here is my directory

[image]

I have also tried

```
prettier --write '/src/*.{ts}
```

and

```
prettier --write './src/*.{ts}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the pattern to:

```
"prettier:write": "prettier --write 'src/*.ts'",
```

Answer (score 0):

feels like you are having an issue with the glob.

try changing from `'src/*.{ts}'` to `'src/**/*.ts'`